# REDHAWK_DEV FAILED on 2.0.0, CentOS 6.7

Tags: redhawksdr

I've installed REDHAWK 2.0.0 from rpms on CentOS 6.7, run shell scripts as required, configured omniORB as required, updated SDRROOT permissions as required, and run `cleanomni` from a terminal command line, but cannot get REDHAWK_DEV to launch in the REDHAWK IDE.  Right-clicking on `Target SDR > Launch Domain...` brings up the "Launch Domain Manager" dialog box with: red 'x" over the label 'Domain Manager'; default Device Manager visible and selectable; and "OK" button greyed out.

Attempting to connect via right-clicking `REDHAWK_DEV > Connect` throws error: `'Connecting Domain' has encountered a problem. Failed to connect to REDHAWK_DEV'`, and `Details>>` gives:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error while executing callable.  Caused by org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName'
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the error by hovering over the red x marker in the launch domain dialog. But it's likely one of two problems:

- Stale info in the naming service (try cleanns at the command line, then re-open the dialog), or
- The naming service isn't running (try stopping it, clearing out /var/log/omniORB, and starting it)

The other issue you mentioned (right-click, "Connect" from context menu) is to connect to an already running domain. It doesn't launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that advice.  But hovering over the red 'x' does not make visible any dialog box or tooltip.

I removed the files `error.log`, `omninames-avl.bak`, and `omninames-avl.log` from the directory `/var/log/omniORB`, ran `cleanns`, `cleanes`, and `cleanomni`, stopped and restarted both `omniNames` and `omniEvents`.

But none of these procedures had any effect on the symptom; the default domain is still visible and selectable, but not launchable.