# REDHAWK_DEV domain connection fails on ubuntu 16.04, redhawk 2.0.6

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm trying to connect my computer to a local redhawk domain. After running omniorb4-nameserver and omniorb-eventservice services I enter the IDE and go to "launch domain" option. Then the domain manager starts successfully, but I can't connect to it. The following message appears:

**Failed to connect to Domain REDHAWK_DEV
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error while executing callable. Caused by org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName**

I've already tried to erase the log files in /var/lib/omniorb and /var/lib/omniEvents, stop and start the omniorb4-nameserver abd omniorb-eventservice event services. Nothing worked. My /etc/omniORB.cfg follows the instructions in https://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch2.html#x4-160002.3.

A similar question was proposed in [REDHAWK_DEV FAILED on 2.0.0, CentOS 6.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36271483/7937114), without any useful answer so far.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that "nameclt resolve REDHAWK_DEV/REDHAWK_DEV" results in an IOR, and that "catior IOR:XXXXX" shows an okay IP address for that IOR. This will at least determine if the domain manager is actually registering in the naming service.

Also take a look through Appendix H of the REDHAWK Manual for other troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Ok, I've run the first command and got an IOR. Then I ran "catior IOR:XX" and this is the output:
<< Type ID: "IDL:CF/DomainManager:1.0"
Profiles:
1. IIOP 1.2 10.0.2.15 52695 ".DomainManager..xAY........."
            TAG_ORB_TYPE omniORB ...(continues)....>>

What is strange to me is where the IP 10.0.2.15 has come from (its the IP of interface "enp0s3" of my pc). In /etc/omniorb.cfg I've set "InitRef = NameService=corbaname::127.0.0.1:2809" and 
"InitRef = EventService=corbaloc::127.0.0.1:11169/omniEvents". Any ideas?

Comment: Running "rh_net_diag" gives me the messages: <<No errors detected with Naming Service.===
No Naming Service related errors found with a Domain Manager running on this host == ERROR(Device Manager): Device Manager failed to connect to Domain Manager REDHAWK_DEV on host 10.0.2.15 on port 55463
POSSIBLE SOLUTION: Check firewall settings on host where Domain Manager is running(10.0.2.15) using the command "sudo /sbin/iptables -L" on that host to see if port 55463 is accessible >> Indeed I'm behind a proxy server, but it shouldn't be an issue, since I just want a local domain connection.]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my proxy server was blocking even local connections. 
To solve the problem I had to edit /etc/environment, adding the line
no_proxy="127.0.0.1,127.0.1.1", which were the local IP's I was using, and reboot.